# Unable to call a jQuery function from within .resize()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code:

```
function centerAlign(image, parent) {
    image.load(function() {
        var imageWidth = image.width();
        var parentWidth = parent.width();
        if(imageWidth != 0) {
            var trim = (parentWidth - imageWidth) / 2;
            image.css("marginLeft", trim);
        }
    });
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    centerAlign($(".swiper-slide img"), $(".swiper-slide"));
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    centerAlign($(".swiper-slide img"), $(".swiper-slide"));
});
```

It runs the function on page load however not on window resize. Any thoughts?

Comment: Put function centerAlign inside of image.load

Comment: Seems fine. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/8qmrft67

Comment: @black123 Call the function from within itself? :S

Comment: @isherwood That works fine however I cannot call the centerAlign function from resize for some reason.

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting the problem. It's not that you can't call the function. It's that your function doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: It runs on ready() though?

Comment: I suppose that problem occurs when you calling centerAlign function inside of resize event. Since image.load is executed only once when DOM is ready, it is not possible to execute resize event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, I was calling load within resize. Guessing as it's already loaded it wont run on resize. Changed to:

```
function centerAlign(image, parent) {
    var imageWidth = image.width();
    var parentWidth = parent.width();
    if(imageWidth != 0) {
        var trim = (parentWidth - imageWidth) / 2;
        image.css("marginLeft", trim);
    }
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    centerAlign($(".swiper-slide img"), $(".swiper-slide"));
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".swiper-slide img").load(function() {
        centerAlign($(".swiper-slide img"), $(".swiper-slide"));
    });
});
```

Now I'm only calling load within ready() and not within resize(). Hope this helps anyone else.

Comment: You have to wait a day, I will when I can.